# Tagged port does not work (switch netgear)

Tags: switch, vlan, pfsense, netgear

I have configured 2 VLANs with firewall (pfsense), but when I set port as tagged in each Vlan, every device lost wan connection and even IP address... I have no idea what could possibly be wrong. Please, help me.

---

Pfsense configuration:

LAN:

- 192.168.1.1/24
- DHCP server - enabled (192.168.1.100 - 192.168.1.199)

VLAN20:

- Parent interface: LAN
- 192.168.20.1/24
- DHCP server - enabled (192.168.20.100 - 192.168.20.199)
- Rules: wildcard

VLAN30:

- Parent interface: LAN
- 192.168.30.1/24
- DHCP server - enabled (192.168.30.100 - 192.168.30.199)
- Rules: wildcard

---

Switch configuration (Netgear GS724t):

VLANS:

- VLAN1 (default)
- VLAN20
- VLAN30

Ports:

- 1 - Tagged 1, 20, 30 ; PVID: 1
- 3 - Untagged: 20 ; PVID: 20
- 5 - Untagged: 30 ; PVID: 30
- Rest of ports: Untagged: 1; PVID: 1

Comment: How have you configured your switch for these VLANs?

Comment: Vlans: 1, 20, 30 |
Port 1 - Tagged: 1, 20, 30; PVID: 1; Connected with WAN |
Port 3 - Untagged: 20; PVID: 20 |
Port 5 - Untagged 30; PVID 30 |
Rest of ports: Untagged: 1; PVID: 1

Comment: Please edit the question and additional information there. Please also try to make it as readable as possible, as it is quite hard to see how everything is mapped here. From description above I see you run your WAN port as tagged with multiple tags. Does the device that is connected to WAN port also have the same mappings?

Comment: Done, hope this helps

Comment: Did you renew DHCP lease on the client machines after changing VLAN?

Comment: yes, multiple times:(